# DNS management: Route mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com using an Amazon loadbalancer

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

**I mistakenly asked this question in stackoverlow however, it probably makes more sense here.**

My application is on amazon and i am using their EC2 loadbalancer.  Amazon states on their site:

```
DNS Name: XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Note: Because the set of IP addresses associated with a LoadBalancer can change over time, 
you should never create an "A" record with any specific IP address. If you want to use a friendly 
DNS name for your LoadBalancer instead of the name generated by the Elastic Load Balancing 
service, you should create a CNAME record for the LoadBalancer DNS name. For more information 
about CNAME records, see the CNAME Record Wikipedia article.
```

I created a CNAME record host `www` mapping to the loadbalancer above in the DNS.  `http://www.mydomain.com` forwards to the right appserver.  (Cool)

However, I noticed that when I type `mydomain.com` instead of `http://www.mydomain.com` it goes to the default A record which is mapped to a different IP and not the loadbalancer.  How do I fix this?  I want both www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com to go to the same loadbalancer.  I think I need to do this in the DNS, right?

Note: I verified the above by pinging both addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want both www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com to go to the same loadbalancer.

You can't. **This is a known design limitation,** which comes from a combination of how Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) is implemented and long standing design choices for DNS.

You cannot make a CNAME entry for your naked 2nd level domain. I.e. `yourdomain.com` must be an A-Record pointing directly to an IP address.

However, Amazon's ELB depends on a custom DNS & EC2 platform created by Amazon, which requires your DNS entry to be a CNAME pointing to your Amazon ELB domain name (i.e. `XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`).

Taken together, what this basically means is that you can only use 3rd level domain names with ELB, for example `www.yourdomain.com` or `blog.yourdomain.com` . And these have to be CNAMES, pointing to your ELB instance.

**So for the naked 2nd level domain `yourdomain.com` (@) itself you must:**

- make an A-Record
- point this A-Record at a HTTP redirector
- have the redirector issue a [temporary or permanent HTTP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to the fully qualified domain name you want to use.

Just about any decent domain registrar or DNS host should have a free or very cheap way of doing this. You could also do it yourself, by running an EC2 instance with a webserver on it, but why bother...

I don't know GoDaddy's UI for this looks, as I have never used them myself. But f.x. Gandi has free-of-charge HTTP redirection called "Web Forwarding", and GoDaddy seems to have a "[Site Redirect Manager](http://help.godaddy.com/article/5120)".

In real life, this isn't really an issue for end users. After a short while all search engine indexing and all end user bookmarks will point to `www.yoursite.com`, so the number of users who enter through `yoursite.com` and get redirected will be tiny. And for those users, it's a short delay (maybe 100-200 ms), and it should only happen once.